# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on Yocto

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a light Linux distribution for a robotic wheelchair application, and was thinking of using Yocto. How can I get ROS Kinetic installed on it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296472/ros-on-yocto/) by [patrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/36225/patrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some quick googling for "ROS Yocto" turns up https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-ros/ , https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros and https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Creating_Recipes_for_ROS_modules

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-06**:
This is the answer. `bmwcarit/meta-ros` is very active and has a good size community.

I don't understand how the OP could not have found this while searching for "ROS Yocto".

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-07-06**:
Most of the references in that project either don't list a ROS version, or refer to "Hydro". It wasn't clear to me at a glance that they also support other ROS version (I suspect they're on a rolling release, but I don't know enough about yocto packages to confirm).

**Comment by [patrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/36225/patrobot/) on 2018-07-08**:
Thanks for the links. Are there differences between ROS on Ubuntu or Yocto?

**Comment by [khasreto](https://answers.ros.org/users/38724/khasreto/) on 2019-10-08**:
Can you share instructions how to setup this meta-ros because instructions are not clear. I mean how to properly add this to bblayer.config and check if it's properly configured. Thanks in advance